# Alternatives for str.substr using <cstring> library?

Tags: c, substring, c-strings

Hi I was wondering if there is an alternative of `str.substring()` in `string.h`. If not, what is an efficient alternative?

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: Those are for C style strings, not std::string. They are from C and have no awareness of std::string.

Comment: ***If not whats an efficient alternative ?*** Use `std::string` in `c++` code and avoid c-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we all agree that using c++ it is safer and more professional to use the standard library tools.

That said, if we're talking about C and not C++, this should be one of the ways to extract a substring with the "string.h" library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char test[] = "abcdef";
    char subtext[3];
    
    memcpy(subtext, &test[1], 2); //Result: "bc"
    subtext[2] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s", subtext);
    
    return 0;
}
```